# line-height are not the same between divs when copied with javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I found this issue which looks to me like a Chrome bug. Interested if others have crossed this one in the past, and if there's any good solution / workaround for it.

**The issue**: when I copy font-size and line-height from one div to an other, they won't look the same: Line-height will seem to differ. Please see Codepen link in the bottom.

**How to reproduce:** 
Create two `divs` or `textareas` with classNames `ta-source` and `ta-target`, and add css for only the first one:

```
.ta-source{font-size: 1.4rem;line-height:1.42857}
```

Insert some multiline text in both, and then add javascript which copies these two properties to the other, so they would match in style:

```
var lh = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".ta-source")).lineHeight
var fs = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".ta-source")).fontSize

document.querySelector(".ta-target").style.lineHeight=lh;
document.querySelector(".ta-target").style.fontSize=fs;
```

That's about it, the two line-heights will seem to differ. Interestingly the issue with other line-heights won't occur, like `line-height:1.42354`. Issue on Firefox or Safari doesn't occur either.

Anyone came across this issue before?

**Issue on Codepen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gVMeVw

```js
var lh = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".ta-source")).lineHeight
var fs = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".ta-source")).fontSize

document.querySelector(".ta-target").style.lineHeight=lh;
document.querySelector(".ta-target").style.fontSize=fs;
```

```css
.ta-target,.ta-source{height:200px;white-space:pre-wrap;float:left}
.ta-source{font-size: 1.4rem;line-height:1.42857}
```

```html
<div class="ta-source">
  this
  is
  a
  simple
  multi
  line
  text
  where
  lines
  dont
  align
  with the other one
</div>
<div class="ta-target">
  this
  is
  a
  simple
  multi
  line
  text
  where
  lines
  dont
  align
  with the other one
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to be a loss of `0.1px` in the `window.getComputedStyle()` that is causing the mismatch. Most probably a Chrome bug.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava, thanks for the input, I agree it must be a Chrome bug. Submitted a bug report, here's the link: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=987568

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do some math:

You set on `.ta-source` `font-size` on `1.4rem`, considering that the root element has font-size to `16px`, the font-size of 1.4rem will correspond to `22.4px`;

on `.ta-source` you also set `line-height:1.42857`,when line-height is defined as a unit-less number, the rule is `the number will be multiplied with the current font size to set the line height`; the current font-size is 22.4px, so it's equivalent to `31,999968px`.

Now, when you get

```
var lh = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".ta-source")).lineHeight
var fs = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".ta-source")).fontSize
```

you receive two rounded numbers in `px`: you don't receive for `lh` nor `1,42857` neither `31,999968px`, but `32px` and for `fs` you don't get the measure in `rem` but in `px`, `22.4px`. These measures are applied to `ta-target`, and I would even say `correctly`.

The differences, indeed, are on `ta-source` and in the way the line-height of `1.42857` equivalent to `31,999968px` is rendered: some browsers rounds up, others down. Chrome rounds it down, Firefox rounds it up; Chrome rounds it to 31px, FIrefox to 32px (try to set in Chrome `line-height` on `.ta-source` to `32px`, everything will align!).

So, the problem lies is the ***subpixel rendering problems***. You will find tons of articles on google.